# SwiftUI initializer apparent circularity

Tags: compiler-errors, initialization, swiftui

**TL:DR**

There seems to be a chicken-and-egg paradox in this `View` initializer.

**The Code**

This happens often enough to me that I must be missing something fundamental about `@State`. Namely the compiler seems to be saying I can't set `pickerIndex` until `pickerIndex` has been set, and I can't exit the initializer without setting `pickerIndex`.

[image]

(The `LetterSelection` variable tracks a letter of the alphabet, but I don't think its details are relevant.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: it is better to provide code "as code", so it could be easier edited*

In the described case it needs to initialize not property value but the state wrapper itself, like

```
self._pickerIndex = State(initialValue: sel.current.idx)
```

Comment: Thank you Asperi. I agree about code, esp. with SwiftUI where it is easy to cut-and-paste runnable examples. In this case I think seeing the (unhelpful) error messages tells a better story. Now, somewhat off-topic I have an ongoing question about your answer of 2020-03-11. I posted it there; no hurry on that. And I have a strange situation where a `View` seems to be laid out _before_ its initializer runs... I will try to isolate and post a small example. It's another case where `@State` behaves non-intuitively. No end to questions.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61661581/swiftui-view-apparently-laid-out-before-init-runs for the above-mentioned "strange situation." Your answer here solves the problem there... but why?